# thousand separated numbers in JSON Grid

Tags: javascript, json, grid, numbers, format

In a JSON Grid , one column is defined as :-

```
{
"dataField": "Number of Days",
"caption":  "Number of Days",
"dataType": "number",
}
```

Output is :

---

```
Number of days 
4125490
```

**What I expect is** : Numbers should be displayed in thousand separated values with commas

**4,125,497**

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function for thousand separator using regex

```js
function thousandSeparator(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
}

console.log(thousandSeparator(4125490))
```

Alternatively use [**toLocaleString**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) to add comma.Both of this ways will return the result in string format

```js
console.log((4125490).toLocaleString('en'))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for decimal points. May be you should edit it a bit

Comment: {
       "dataField": "Number of Days",
       "caption":  "Number of Days",
       "cellTemplate": function (container, options) {
       var num = moment(options.text).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
       $('<div>').html(num).appendTo(container);
       }      
        },

now output is : Thu Feb 01 2,001 00:00:00 GMT-0,800
idk where is it picking date and time from ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var n = 34523453.345
n.toLocaleString() //returns "34,523,453.345"
```

Comment: It is good to give some explanation of your answer. Otherwise it will treat as a low quality post and may be got deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let numStr = "41123123.1231"
let x = numStr.split('.')[0]
let commaString = ""
for (i = 0; i<x.length ; i++){ 
  commaString+= x[i]; 
  if ((x.length-i-1) % 3 ===0 && (x.length-i-1)!==0) {
    commaString += ',';
  }
}
commaString = numStr.split('.')[1] ? [commaString, numStr.split('.')[1]].join('.') : commaString
console.log(commaString)
```

Comment: And it is obviously not working for numbers with decimal points in them. user2779185's answer works perfectly fine

Comment: edited my code so that it works for decimal points as well... but meh!! there are many lines to it

Answer (score 0):

```js
function thousandSeparator(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
}

console.log(thousandSeparator(4125429023.12322))
```